# extracting text AND Images from PDF file

Tags: java, image, pdf, text, extract

I have been bumping my head against the wall with this one, have researched and pretty much tried every library suggested to me. I am currently trying to write a program in java that will extract text AND images from a pdf file and allow me to write the extracted content to a word file. I have managed to extract the content using the ICEpdf library, however the problem is that I need to be able to write the content in the exact same order as it was read. So, to clarify, I need a library that will help me keep track of where exactly in the page the text and images are situated so I can put them in the same place in my word file.

Comment: This is doomed to never work properly by design. There are a *lot* of ways to make images and text appear in a PDF. You may get it to work with PDF's created by a single source (sufficient for you?), but never reliably with any PDF.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF to Word converter is a horribly complex proposition.

Your best bet will probably to use Open Office to do it for you and not even try to handle the intermediate steps.

http://www.openoffice.org/api/

Comment: How would I got about using openOffice to do that? Does it support direct conversion from PDF to MS Word? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [Advanced PDF parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449903/advanced-pdf-parser-for-java)

OFF:

-Also to my knowledge there is a python parser that sorta converts the pdf to html (that way you can keep track of the ordering of the objects within the pdf). I know its not java, but you might be able to use the output.
http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html