# How do you read a .PDF file the same way you read .txt file using scanner. This is in java for android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I am trying to read a .pdf file the same way you read a .txt file. I need to parse the pdf file to obtain some information.

Comment: and you haven't researched anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced PDF parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449903/advanced-pdf-parser-for-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read PDF files using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Refering to this Stack Exchange article
(Your question is probably a duplicate)

[How to read PDF files using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

Use a library like Apache's PDFBox to do it.

Please do some basic research next time before you ask a question, I found tons of answers in about three minutes.

Cheers!

Comment: I want a native solution. no libraries

Comment: Lol you just came back, i gave this answer 6 months ago

Comment: I don't come here often. I a pretty go collection of reference books. But this kind of stuff is not really  in any of them